# Difference between QoS and rmw_qos_profile

Tags: ros2, dds

Can someone explain to me the difference between the `rclcpp::Qos` class and the `rclcpp::rmw_qos_profile_t` class?

To me, it seems that the first is just an encapsulation of the latter. And if, so, why do some constructors (see `rclcpp::Publisher`) use `rclcpp::Qos` and some other (see `rclcpp::message_filter::Subscriber`) use `rclcpp::rmw_qos_profile_t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rclcpp::QoS` class was introduced [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/713). As the main reason is mentioned: 'Adds an rclcpp version of QoS, which requires the history depth to be specified if using "keep last"'.

> why do some constructors use rclcpp::Qos and some other use rclcpp::rmw_qos_profile_t

A quick look through the `rclcpp` PR's reveals e.g.:

- [This one](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/1964), introducing `rclcpp::QoS` for `create_client` and
- [This one](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/1969) for `create_service`.

Note that these PR's are a lot more recent than the initial PR introducing `rclcpp::QoS`.

So I think the reason some constructors still take a `rmw_qos_profile_t` is probably just because nobody had the time to change those yet.

Side note on the question:

My best-practice to find this kind of knowledge is to:

- Go to the code in Github,
- Find a relevant line (e.g. a class definition or a specific method),
- Click on the line number,
- Choose 'View git blame' and
- Read through the pull requests that influenced that part of the code.

This generally leads to design info and discussions about design choices.

Final remark: `rmw_qos_profile_t` is not part of `rclcpp` but of `rmw`. It is defined [here](https://github.com/ros2/rmw/blob/83445be486deae8c78d275e092eafb4bf380bd49/rmw/include/rmw/types.h#L574-L619).

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I often get stuck on little details like this and your tips will definitely help me in the future :)